# MAX number from excel column of type general

Tags: excel, vba

My setup looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2jNS.png)

```
=MAX(B3:B99999)+1
```

This works if the cell values are type general. However, if `B3:B99999` are strings how can you calculate the value?

Comment: Your question is unclear regarding what value you want to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make a small change, namely placing `--` before the range and use `SUMPRODUCT` to deal with the array:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--B3:B99999))+1
```

Comment: in cell iam getting #VALUE!

Comment: @AnushaVinod, I updated the formula to make it easier for you to use